# How to give serial no to records with condition in Mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-statements

I have a table in where two type of products are stored. One table for single item with unique id and the other is for combination of items having the same Id for one combination like in the image below:

[image: Mysql Table Snip]

I have to run an update query in my SQL, which will give serial number `Sno` for this.
If the `DealCode` is the same, assign same serial number, otherwise increment it. Pleae note that if the `DealCode` is 0 then it should be incremented. 0's are for different product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be this will help you-

you can perform the mentioned task via creating a stored procedure for this

lets suppose you have a table named "product"

**stored procedure defination --**

```
DELIMITER $$ 
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS assignSerialNo$$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE `assignSerialNo`() 
BEGIN 
DECLARE x  INT; 
DECLARE y  INT; 
DECLARE data  INT; 
DECLARE countNonZeroRecord  INT; 
DECLARE countZeroRecord  INT;

SET x = 1; 
SET countNonZeroRecord = ( SELECT count(*) FROM  product where DealCode != 0 ); 
SET countZeroRecord = ( SELECT count(*) FROM  product where DealCode = 0 );


WHILE x  <= countZeroRecord  DO 
SET data = ( SELECT WebTransactionDetailNo from product WHERE Sno = 0 LIMIT 1 ); 
UPDATE product SET Sno = x WHERE  WebTransactionDetailNo = data; SET  x = x + 1;  
END WHILE;

SET y = 1; 
WHILE y  <= countNonZeroRecord  DO 
SET data = ( SELECT DealCode from product WHERE Sno = 0 AND DealCode !=0 LIMIT 1 ); 
UPDATE product SET Sno = x WHERE  DealCode = data; SET  x = x + 1;  
SET  y = y + 1; 
END WHILE;

END
```

**Call the procedure** for setting the serial no. for records by using the syntax -

## call assignSerialNo()

**

### For PHP:

if you want to do the above task with core php then you can use the below code :
hope this will help you

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("hostName","userName","password","databaseName");
$x=0; 

$nonZeroDealCodeResult = runQuery("SELECT count(*) as countRecords FROM  product where DealCode != 0",$connection);
$zeroDealCodeResult = runQuery("SELECT count(*) as countRecords FROM  product where DealCode = 0",$connection);

while($zeroDealCodeResult['countRecords']) { 
$x++;
$searchQuery = "SELECT WebTransactionDetailNo from product WHERE Sno = 0 AND DealCode = 0  LIMIT 1";
$data = runQuery($searchQuery,$connection);
mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE product SET Sno = {$x} WHERE  WebTransactionDetailNo = {$data['WebTransactionDetailNo']}"); 
$zeroDealCodeResult['countRecords']--;
}

while($nonZeroDealCodeResult['countRecords']) {
$x++;  
$searchQuery = "SELECT DealCode from product WHERE Sno = 0 AND DealCode !=0 LIMIT 1";
$data = runQuery($searchQuery,$connection);
mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE product SET Sno = {$x} WHERE  DealCode = {$data['DealCode']}"); 
$nonZeroDealCodeResult['countRecords']--;
}

function runQuery($searchQuery,$connection) {
$dataQuery = mysqli_query($connection, $searchQuery); 
$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dataQuery) ;
return $data;
}

?>
```

Comment: Dear @Jyoti, thanks for your kind reply. Can it be more simplified, or Can i do it through PHP?

Comment: Hi @SaleemJafar , sorry for delay, i have updated the answer for php as well. hopw this will help you.

Comment: Dear @Jyoti, Thank you very much. You really made my day. I have spend too many days to do this task. But i couldn't. Thanks a lot.